# yii2 jquery отправка формы срабатывает только со второго раза

Tags: html, jquery, yii2, валидация

Есть следующая форма с двумя кнопками отправки. Одна для отправки формы без ответа, одна с ответом и проверкой на пустоту поля. Проблема в том что для обоих кнопок отправка формы происходит только со второго клика:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'complaint_feedback',
        'action' => Url::to(['complaints/handle-complaint']),
        'method' => 'POST',
        'options' => ['class' => 'form-respons form-claim-feedback','style'=>'display:none;'],
    ]);
?>
<div id="textarea-group" class="form-group">                                    
    <label for="text-claim" class="hidden-xs">Добавить текст ответа</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="text-claim" rows="3" name="complaint_answer" placeholder="Добавить текст ответа"></textarea>
    <div id="answer_error" class="help-block"></div>
    <input id="complaint_id" name="complaint_id" type="hidden" value="">
</div>  
<div class="clearfix form-btns">
    <button type="button" onclick="$('#complaint_feedback').submit();" class="btn btn-link">Обработать без ответа</button>
    <button id="submit_with_answer" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Для кнопки "Отправить" имеется js-функция:

```
$('#submit_with_answer').click(function() {
            if ($('#text-claim').val().length > 0)
            {
                $('#complaint_feedback').submit();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#textarea-group').addClass('has-error');
                $('#answer_error').html('Заполните поле «Текст ответа»');
            }
        });
```

В чем может быть причина? Данная форма изначально спрятана. При нажатии на определенную кнопку она перемещается внутрь другого элемента и после этого показывается при помощи .show(). Может это с этим связано?

Comment: Добрый вечер. А зачем недоиспользовать виджет ActiveForm? Начали за здравие, а кончили за упокой... По другому Ваш код охарактеризовать нельзя. Начните с правки кода формы.

Comment: @slo_nik, я просто не в курсе как можно через чистый activeform реализовать такой функционал с такими условиями и с двумя submit-ами. Может подскажете?

Comment: Какой функционал? У Вас не работает валидация? Вы хотите изменить шаблон формы? Или Вы не можете использовать свои классы?

Comment: Может быть есть смысл ограничиться одной кнопкой? Хочет пишет текст, хочет так отправляет. Рядом с кнопкой добавить спан, чтобы по клику разворачивалась текстарея.